# Is the XP gain from capturing Pokémon the same as if it fainted?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

In the sixth Generation of Pokémon, you can finally gain experience from capturing Pokémon. Is the amount you gain from capturing the same as if you had defeated the Pokémon? Or is it a percentage, based off health left or other factors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To test this, I went to some wild grass and both killed and caught the same type of pokemon

I caught a wild level 3 Pidgey with my level 6 Chespin and I was awarded 21 experience points.

I killed another level 3 Pidgey while my Chespin was still level 6 and I was awarded 21 experience points.

So yes, the experience is the same.

Comment: How low was the health on the one you caught?

Comment: @SaintWacko If I recall correctly I don't think I did any damage